# Fullcalendar.io Scheduler lost events on view change?

Tags: fullcalendar, scheduler

I'm pulling events in via a json feed(http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) & have the start/end parameters trigger my API to only return events between the 2 dates. Note that I'm using background events to indicate user schedules.

schedules?from=2015-11-25&to=2015-11-27 returns:

```
[
    {
        "id": "4-schedule",
        "resourceId": 4,
        "start": "2015-11-25T12:00:00-0800",
        "end": "2015-11-25T18:30:00-0800",
        "title": "John Doe Scheduled",
        "rendering": "background",
        "backgroundColor": "#a8ceff"
    },
    {
        "id": "4-schedule",
        "resourceId": 4,
        "start": "2015-11-26T09:00:00-0800",
        "end": "2015-11-26T17:00:00-0800",
        "title": "John Doe Scheduled",
        "rendering": "background",
        "backgroundColor": "#a8ceff"
    }
]
```

I'm planning on appending my actual events to that array & should work find but I just noticed this morning that while navigating prev/next to different days will successfully query my API for those days, if I switch to week or month view & then back to day my events are gone :/

Comment: We may need to see more code to find the issue. The script that initializes the fullcalendar, the json code, and any callback functions you have for the calendar would help.

Comment: Actually it looks like it's working now. Not sure why but perhaps because I was having those issues when I only had background events on the calendar. Once I added additional type events there were no further issues, even on the days I only have background events..